# why don't zipkin have support to trace database container?

Tags: trace, zipkin

I have the microservice architecture of E-commerce website with all kinds of service containers and its corresponding database containers. I failed to find a library to purely trace database running time for each request in like mongodb or mysql, so I used tcpdump to check the HTTP request roundtime at the port of service container. The total communication time is always shorter than Zipkin's log time for that HTTP request. So I am assuming that Zipkin include some service container process time in the tracing, which is not what I desire to have. I plan to use tcpdump on database container and decode the package for tracing id, which could be a lot of hassle.

Why can't zipkin track this activity, or there might be some tools I can use?